# Is the "size" field in file_managed used for anything?

Tags: 7, files

I'm having to import videos and video thumbnails manually to the file_managed table since there is no migrate support for it yet.

I'm wondering if the size is really used for anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used in a few places:

- [`theme_file_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7) where it's used to add microformat data to a file link (per http://microformats.org/wiki/file-format-examples).
- [`file_space_used()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_space_used/7) where it's used to "determine total disk space used by a single user or the whole filesystem".
- [`file_validate_size()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_validate_size/7) where it's used to "check that the file's size is below certain limits".

It's probably a good idea to fill this field in if you're able, or at least run a small script to do so after you've manually entered the records. Something like this maybe:

```
// The filesize column defaults to 0 so it's an easy check.
$fids = db_query('SELECT fid FROM {file_managed} WHERE filesize = 0')->fetchCol();

// Loop through the files and update the file size field.
foreach (file_load_multiple($fids) as $file) {
  $file->filesize = filesize($file->uri);
  file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: sweet! Very helpful, thank you! Is there a way to lookup in the API docs which functions use those field or did you just happen to know them?

Comment: I had a feeling if it was used it'd either be in `file.inc` or somewhere in the core `file` module so I just did a search for the string *filesize* in those files...and up popped those functions :)

Comment: This is also a handy code blip to run periodically if you or your users upload directly to the filesystem.

Comment: Setting the filesize before calling file_save does not seem to make a difference as file_save overrides it but recalculating it. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save/7 Plus, if the uri is in streams format like 'public://docs' for example, the filesize calculation fails, and as a result, filesize is set to 0 once again. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

Another use for the `filesize` column is with Views.  If you create a view over a content type with filefields, you can create a relationship to the `fid`.  When you do this, a **File** group appears in the fields.  One of the new fields is **File: Size**.  Very handy when you make a list of downloads attached to a node.

Answer (score 0):

DRUPAL 8

Updated version of the above

```
// The filesize column defaults to 0 so it"s an easy check.
$fids = db_query("SELECT fid FROM {file_managed} WHERE filesize > 0")->fetchCol();

// Loop through the files and update the file size field.
foreach (file_load_multiple($fids) as $file) {
 echo $file->getSize(). " ";
 $uri = $file->getFileUri();
 $stream_wrapper_manager = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaUri($uri);
 $file_path = $stream_wrapper_manager->realpath();
 $file->setSize(filesize($file_path));
 $file->save();
}
```

I use it with *drush php-eval '...'*