# Changing the file of a file field (drupal 7)

Tags: 7, files

I have a content type that contains a file field which is always a .zip file.  When a file is uploaded I have a module that unzips the file to make a few changes then re zips the file to a new location.  I would like to associate this newly created .zip file with my content type but so far I have not been able to find a way to do that.  I initially tried to change the url of the file field in which it worked temporarily but it seems that the file field was later re-saved with the initial value.

I do my unzipping and re-zipped from hook_node_presave (I also tried to do from hook_node_insert) but neither seemed to work.  Could anyone offer me any advice about how to change the file of a file field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File fields are referenced by their ID in the `file_managed` table; as well as updating the field in your presave hook, you'll probably need to update the file entity that relates to that id with the new filename/path.

This is just a basic example but it should give you a starting point:

```
// Get the file id from the field
$fid = $node->field_file[$node->language][0]['fid'];

// Load the file
$file = file_load($fid);

// Update the filename
$file->filename = basename($new_path);

// Update the uri (this must be in the format of a schema uri, e.g. public://folder/file.jpg
$file->uri = $new_path;

// Save the changes
file_save($file);
```

You might also want to update the `filesize` field; it's [used in a few places](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23756/is-the-size-field-in-file-managed-used-for-anything) in the system.